# Custom Metric fed with imported data against Product SKU acting weird

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, data-import

I've created a new custom metrics to import metrics associated with product sku. I've used the data import function to feed this custom metric. Data are successfully imported.

However, the imported data doesn't match the value I have in the csv file...

I've also built a report using Product SKU as dimension and with the new custom metrics, I don't understand why but this custom metrics is changing over time when it supposed to be fixed... or I missing something.

Here is the Data Set schema :

```
Key: ga:productSku
Imported Data: ga:metric13
Overwrite hit data: Yes
```

ga:metric13 has just been created especially for this data import.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found the answer. My question wasn't clear. I didn't know what was my issue. I've started importing data with the assumption that Custom Dimension and Custom Metrics were somehow similar. There are not. Custom metrics are incremented for each hit where the custom metrics are collected. So basically when reporting a custom metrics against product SKU the value of the custom metric will be equal to the number of hits * value of the custom metrics imported.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas of what could have gone wrong...?

I assume you are using the processing-time import (different from query-time import). Processing-time import would only work for the future data, not past (unless you link to a date dimension).
Because Google Analytics aggregates the data, your metric will be attached to products interactions happened after your import was successful.

Another possible failure point is an import key. It should match values in GA exactly

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. I've created a new custom metrics so as far as I know there should be no value at all or the right value but not some random numbers. Import Key is right too. I've checked and checked my csv file.